AWS API Gateway limit beyond 29 seconds - not being respected?
As a follow up to How can I set the AWS API Gateway timeout higher than 30 seconds?, I've successfully increased my account-level service-quota timeout for this region to 120,000 ms beyond the 29,000 ms default (designed to handle a downstream LLM call via bedrock).
I have the following cloudformation template snippet to which I've added the increased timeout.
However, the gateway is still timing out with a 504 at 29 seconds according to my front-end client!
Is the update not being respected, or propagating? Is it a regional issue? HTTP vs REST type?
Please assist, thanks!
  MyApiMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      HttpMethod: "POST"
      ResourceId: !Ref MyApiResource
      RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
      AuthorizationType: "NONE"
      Integration:
        Type: "AWS_PROXY"
        IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"
        Uri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${PrimaryLambdaFunction.Arn}/invocations"
        TimeoutInMillis: 120000  # Increased from default of 29 secs via account-level service quota increase
      MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: '200'  # Update to match the expected success status
          ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'POST,OPTIONS'"
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"


According to the announcement  increasing the timeout beyond 29 seconds is only possible for Regional REST APIs and private REST APIs but not for HTTP APIs

@derpirscher Thank you, that's what I feared. How would I convert my gateway?

This blogentry might help you  https://dev.to/slsbytheodo/migrating-from-api-gateway-v2-to-v1-to-get-rest-api-features-nfp

@derpirscher Thank you that's help. It looks like I may already be using rest api since I have Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi, but clearly I am not because of the lack of respect of the increased limit. Thanks for any and all assistance!

In fact the Console confirms this: Protocol = REST in the table of APIs. But clearly it's not?

It's probably that it's not REGIONAL, looking now.

I had to set the protocol to REGIONAL in the cloudformation template to make this work.
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: "MyApp"
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - REGIONAL

With thanks to @derpirscher for the guidance and inspiration!
